# How to input and output partitioned matrices that show partitions and compute as normal?

Tags: matrix

I want to demonstrate multiplication of partitioned matrices as in the example [here](http://math.nyu.edu/~neylon/linalgfall04/project1/dj/multpartmatrices.htm). Using the Insert Menu, you can build a matrix and draw lines between rows and columns. However, I want to be able to select a subset of the column and row lines to add. Then I would like to be able to compute the product of two compatible matrices (so the column partition on the left matrix matches the row partition on the right matrix) and have the output show as a partitioned matrix where the row dividers come from the row dividers on the left matrix and the column dividers come from the column dividers on the right matrix. In the example, this matrix multiplication is defined since the column partition on A is, say, {2} and the same for the row partition on B. The resulting matrix C has a row divider after the 2nd row since A had a row divider after the second row (while B had no column dividers).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
a = {{3, 0, -1}, {-5, 2, 4}, {-2, -6, 3}};
b = {{1, 2}, {-3, 4}, {2, 1}};

grdF = Grid[#1, Dividers -> {#2, #3}] &;

ga = grdF[a, {3 -> Red}, {3 -> Red}];
gb = grdF[b, False, {3 -> Red}];
gab = grdF[ga[[1]].gb[[1]],First[Dividers /. Options[gb]], Last[ Dividers /. Options[ga]]];

Row[{ga, "\[Times]", gb, " = ", gab}, Spacer[3]]
```

[image]

**Update:** Wrapping matrices with square brackets:

```
 bracketF = (ToBoxes[#] /. 
  TagBox[x : GridBox[__], y__] :> 
   TagBox[RowBox[{StyleBox["[", SpanMaxSize -> \[Infinity]], x, 
      StyleBox["]", SpanMaxSize -> \[Infinity]]}], y] // DisplayForm) &;

 Row[{bracketF@ga, "\[Times]", bracketF@gb, " = ", bracketF@ gab}, Spacer[3]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That is better and easier than I expected. I have been wondering in general how to express matrices with [ ] 's around them, instead of ( )'s. Is there a way to wrap these matrices in [ ] 's? If so, would this method extend to a way to do so for matrices in other cells such as Text cells?

Comment: I came up with this for wrapping the matrix with []. But I simply combine this with the function given. `matrixform[mat_] := 
 RowBox[{StyleBox["[", SpanMaxSize -> \[Infinity]], GridBox[mat], 
     StyleBox["]", SpanMaxSize -> \[Infinity]]}] // DisplayForm // 
  TraditionalForm`

Comment: Edit to the above comment. But I can't simply combine these functions. Any ideas on how to do so?

Comment: Found a modification of `matrixform` above that handles dividers:    
matrixform2 = DisplayForm[RowBox[{StyleBox["[", SpanMaxSize -> \[Infinity]], GridBox[#1,GridBoxDividers -> {"Columns" -> ReplacePart[Table[False, {Dimensions[#1][[2]]}],(Map[List, #2] + 1) -> Red], "Rows" -> ReplacePart[Table[False, {Dimensions[#1][[1]]}], (Map[List, #3] + 1) -> Red]}], StyleBox["]", SpanMaxSize -> \[Infinity]]}]] &;  
  
`matrixform2[a,{2},{2}]` does what I want but not `matrixform2[a.b,{2},{2}]`

Comment: I can pass in 2a or `a+1` but I cannot pass in a product of matrices. Any ideas of how to change that?

Comment: @Ben, please see the update for a way to wrap matrices with square brackets.

Comment: That answers what I originally asked very well. Your use of `Options` in `gab` and `ToBox` and `TagBox` in `bracketF` taught me a few things. I was hoping to extend your `bracketF` to an ordinary matrix but what comes out looks like an ordinary matrix (the FullForm suggests otherwise). I don't know if the `matrixform` I came up with above is the right approach, but it does take in a ordinary matrix and outputs in [ ] 's. However, if I pass in a product `a.b` or even if I execute `a.b` and then use `%` in `matrix form`, what comes out is not nice. Why is this happening? How to modify?

Comment: @Ben, it is indeed puzzling that `matrixform2` does not work with `a.b` -- that could be a good new question to post. Re extending `bracketF` to work with an ordinary matrix, there must be a cleaner and more direct way to do it, but a quick-and-dirty way is to use `Composition[bracketF,Grid]`.