# How to add a vertical line to a matrix?

Tags: matrix, output-formatting

Today, I want to write a program to show the solving process of a the inverse of a matrix, and I use the `Elementary Transformation`, so I need to add a vertical *dashed line* to the matrix.

I hope the result looks like this:

> [image]

#### Question

Is it possible to achieve this effect?

#### Update1:

**Firstly, thanks for Öskå's answer**

For example, I have the following augmented matrix,

```
augmentedMatrix[n_Integer] := 
  Join[
    RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {n, n}], IdentityMatrix@n, 2]

augmentedMatrix[6] // MatrixForm
```

> [image]

Then I need the result shown as below. Namely,
 `myStyle[augmentedMatrix[6]]`$$\Rightarrow$$

> [image]

#### Update2:

Öskå's answer, the final effect that apply `augmentedMatrixForm` to my function:

```
  augmentedMatrixForm[mat_?MatrixQ] :=
   Module[{middlemat, len},
    len = Length@First@mat;
    middlemat = {Take[#, len/2] & /@ mat, Take[#, -len/2] & /@ mat};
    MatrixForm@
     List@Grid[
      List@(TableForm[#, TableSpacing -> {1, 1}] & /@ middlemat), 
       Dividers -> {# -> 
        Directive[Red, Dashed] & /@ (Range@Length@middlemat)[[2 ;;]]}]
  ]
```

> [image]

I found that the matrix *cannot* align beautifully `when the matrix contained fraction`.

Comment: Related Q/A: [How to input and output partitioned matrices that show partitions ...](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55609/125)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Grid.html) directly supports such lines, called [`Dividers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dividers.html):

```
m = augmentedMatrix[6];

g = Grid[m, Dividers -> {7 -> {Red, Dashed}}]
```

[image]

All that remains is to incorporate the large ( ) brackets used by `MatrixForm`:

```
MatrixForm[{{g}}]
```

[image]

Another approach is to realize that both `MatrixForm` and `Grid` produce a [`GridBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GridBox.html) expression:

```
Shallow[ToBoxes @ MatrixForm[m], 5]
Shallow[ToBoxes @ Grid[m], 3]
```

> ```
> TagBox[RowBox[{(,,GridBox[<<5>>],,)}],Function[BoxForm`e$,BoxForm`e$]]
>
> TagBox[GridBox[<<3>>],Grid]
> ```

We can manipulate that Box data to get the desired result:

```
ToBoxes @ MatrixForm[m] /. 
  GridBox[x__] :> 
   GridBox[x, GridBoxDividers -> {"ColumnsIndexed" -> {7 -> {Red, Dashed}}}] // 
     DisplayForm
```

[image]

The more verbose syntax required (replacement, and `GridBoxDividers` etc.) is certainly not ideal, but I think it is useful to understand that at a fundamental level all these functions are working with the same FrontEnd Box "primitives."

#### Proposal

Finally, here is what I propose for actual use, packaging the first method above into a hopefully convenient form.

```
Format[matWithDiv[n_, opts : OptionsPattern[Grid]][m_?MatrixQ]] := 
  MatrixForm[{{Grid[m, opts, Dividers -> {n -> {Red, Dashed}}]}}]
```

Now:

```
augmentedMatrix[6] // matWithDiv[7]
```

[image]

Additional `Grid` options can be used:

```
augmentedMatrix[6] // matWithDiv[7, Background -> LightOrange]
```

[image]

You can of course combine the formatting with the matrix generation, e.g.:

```
augMat2[n_, opts: OptionsPattern[Grid]] := augmentedMatrix[n] // matWithDiv[n + 1, opts]

augMat2[4]
```

[image]

```
augMat2[5, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Be aware that, like `MatrixForm`, you will need to extract the first part of the output if you wish to manipulate the raw matrix data:

```
augMat2[5, Frame -> All] // First
```

> ```
> {{8, 9, 9, 5, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
>  {7, 7, 4, 6, 6, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
>  {4, 5, 4, 10, 6, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
>  {7, 4, 2, 7, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
>  {7, 2, 9, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}
> ```

Comment: Dear Mr.Wizard, +1,Firstly, thanks sincerely, In addition, your solution always detaied and rigorous, as well as surprised me. :-)

Comment: @Tangshutao You're welcome, and thanks for the Accept.

Answer (score 7):

```
SeedRandom@0;
mat = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {2, 3, 3}];
MatrixForm@List@Grid[List@(TableForm /@ mat), Dividers -> {2 -> Directive[Red, Dashed]}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course you can play with spacings: `TableForm[#, TableSpacing -> {1, 1}] & /@ mat`

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

---

To go a bit further with `Dividers`:

```
SeedRandom@0;
mat = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {10, 3, 3}];
MatrixForm@
 List@Grid[List@(TableForm[#, TableSpacing -> {1, 1}] & /@ mat), 
   Dividers -> {# -> Directive[Red, Dashed] & /@ (Range@Length@mat)[[2 ;;]]}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

---

With the new matrix (I removed the `Join`) it works the same:

```
augmentedMatrix[n_Integer] := {RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {n, n}], IdentityMatrix@n}
mat = augmentedMatrix[6];
MatrixForm@
 List@Grid[List@(TableForm[#, TableSpacing -> {1, 1}] & /@ mat), 
   Dividers -> {# -> Directive[Red, Dashed] & /@ (Range@Length@mat)[[2 ;;]]}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @Tangshutao You should not Accept an answer so quickly.  I was working on an answer and it is disheartening to see that you feel that no additional answers are useful.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Knowing that you will pwnd me :)

Comment: @Öskå I wouldn't say that; I just have a different approach.

Comment: @Tangshutao That took longer than expected, but I rethought what I was writing half way through and started over.  I hope that my answer will now both give a useful method and some understanding of the low-level Front End functions in play here.