# Find Elementary Matrices that produce RREF

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have a matrix, `M`, which I am reducing to RREF using `RowReduce[M]`. I would like to know the elementary matrices which perform the row reducing operations on `M` during `RowReduce[M]` to reduce it to RREF, or at least the product of them all.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Update April 29 2023** There is a newer version here [Show steps in finding the reduced row echelon form of a symbolic matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284439/show-steps-in-finding-the-reduced-row-echelon-form-of-a-symbolic-matrix) which now works on symbolic matrices also.

---

**edit** May 12, 2022. Added frame around pivot element as it moves to make it easier to see.

---

I've updated `displayRREF` to now handle all cases (no solution, unique solution, infinite number of solutions).

It also now does RREF only on a matrix on its own if no `b` vector is given.

But if a `b` is given as well, then it will also solve the system $Ax = b$.

I've kept the original answer below, but that old code can now be replaced by this newer version. One day I might make this a resource function when I have sometime.

Since I wrote this in code cell. Posting the code here might not display as easy to read as in the notebook. So here is a **link** to the notebook also [RREF.nb](https://12000.org/tmp/RREF_may_8_2022/RREF.nb)

First, here are some usage examples.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Source code

```
 displayMatrix[A_?(MatrixQ[#]&),dashed_?BooleanQ]:= If[dashed,displayMatrix[A,Last@Dimensions[A]],Print[MatrixForm[A]]]
 displayMatrix[A_?(MatrixQ[#]&),nCols_Integer]:= Print[A[[All,1;;nCols]]//matWithDiv[nCols,Background->LightOrange]]
displayRREF[Ain_?(MatrixQ[#]&),dashed_:False]:=Module[
  {multiplier,j,i,pivotRow,pivotCol,nRows,nCols,p,tmp,startAgain,A=Ain,n,m,pivotsFound={},keepEliminating,nIter},
    displayMatrix[A,dashed];
    {nRows,nCols} = Dimensions[A];
    
    keepEliminating=True;
    
    n=1; m=1;
    nIter = 0;
    While[keepEliminating,
        nIter++;
        If[nIter>100, (*safe guard*)
             Return["Internal error. Something went wrong. Or very large system?",Module]
        ];
        
        If[dashed && m==nCols,
             keepEliminating=False 
        ,
             Print["Pivot is A(",n,",",m,")"];
             Print@makeNiceMatrix[A,{n,m},dashed];
             If[A[[n,m]] != 0,
                  If[A[[n,m]] != 1,
                       A[[n,All]] = A[[n,All]]/A[[n,m]];
                       Print["Making the pivot 1 using using row(",n,")= row(",n,")/A(",n,",",m,")"]
                       (*Print@makeNiceMatrix[A,{n,m},dashed]*)
                 ];
                 If[n<nRows,
                       Do[
                            If[A[[j,m]] != 0,
                                  multiplier = A[[j,m]]/A[[n,m]];
                                  Print["Zeroing out element A(",j,",",m,") using row(",j,")=",multiplier,"*row(",n,")-row(",j,")"];
                                  A[[j,m;;]] = A[[j,m;;]] - multiplier*A[[n,m;;]];
                                  Print@makeNiceMatrix[A,{n,m},dashed];
                            ]
                       ,{j,n+1,nRows}
                       ];
                  ];
                  pivotsFound = AppendTo[pivotsFound,{n,m}];
                  If[n==nRows,
                         keepEliminating=False
                  ,
                      n++;
                      m++   
                  ]
            ,
                  (*pivot is zero*)
                  Print["Pivot is zero"];
                  (*Print@makeNiceMatrix[A,{n,m},dashed];*)
                  If[n==nRows&&m==nCols, keepEliminating=False
                  ,
                       (*pivot is zero. If we can find non-zero pivot row below, then exchange rows*)
                       If[n<nRows,
                             p = FirstPosition[A[[n+1;;,m]],_?(#!=0&)];
                             If[ p===Missing["NotFound"]|| Length[p]==0,
                                  If[m<nCols,
                                       m++
                                  ,
                                       keepEliminating=False
                                  ]
                             ,
                                  (*found non zero pivot below. Exchange rows*)
                                  tmp = A[[n,All]];
                                  A[[n,All]] = A[[First[p]+n,All]];
                                  A[[First[p]+n,All]] = tmp;
                                  Print["Exchanging row(",n,") and row(",First[p]+n,")"]
                                  (*Print@makeNiceMatrix[A,{n,m},dashed]*)
                            ]
                      ,
                            If[m<nCols,
                                  m++
                            ,
                                  keepEliminating=False
                            ]
                      ]
                  ]
             ]
        ]
    ];
         
    
    (*pivotsFound = DeleteDuplicates[pivotsFound];*)
    Print[">>>>>>Starting backward elimination phase. The pivots are ",pivotsFound];
    Do[ 
        pivotRow=First@entry;
        pivotCol=Last@entry;
        
       
        If[pivotRow>1,
            Do[
                 If[ A[[i,pivotCol]] != 0,
                      Print["Zeroing out element A(",i,",",pivotCol,") using row(",i,")=row(",i,")-A(",i,",",pivotCol,")*row(",pivotRow,")"];
                      A[[i,;;]] = A[[i,;;]] - A[[i,pivotCol]]*A[[pivotRow,;;]];
                      Print@makeNiceMatrix[A,{pivotRow,pivotCol},dashed]
                 ]
            ,
            {i,pivotRow-1,1,-1} 
           ]
        ]
        ,
        {entry,pivotsFound}    
   ];
   
   {A,pivotsFound[[All,2]]}
]
makeSolutionSpecialCase[A_?(MatrixQ[#]&),b_?(VectorQ[#]&),pivotCols_List]:=Module[
   {nRows,nCols,nLeadingVariables,nFreeVariables,n,m,k,variables={},eq,freeVariables,sol={}},
   
    Print["Pivot columns are ",MatrixForm[pivotCols]];
    
    ClearAll[x,t]; (*did not make them local, to prevent $ from showing in print*)
    {nRows,nCols} = Dimensions[A];
    nLeadingVariables = Length[pivotCols];
    nFreeVariables =  nCols-nLeadingVariables;    
    Print["There are ",nLeadingVariables," leading variables and ",nFreeVariables," free variables. These are "];
    
    Array[t, nFreeVariables];
    Array[x, nCols];
    
    m=0;k=0;
    Do[
        If[Not[MemberQ[pivotCols,n]],
            m++;
            Print[x[n]," is a free variable. Let ",x[n],"=",t[m]];
            AppendTo[variables,t[m]];
            AppendTo[sol,0]
        ,
            Print[x[n]," is a leading variable"];
            AppendTo[variables,x[n]];
            AppendTo[sol,b[[++k]]]
        ]
    ,{n,1,nCols}
    ];
    
    freeVariables=(t[#]&/@Range[nFreeVariables]);
    Print["Hence the system after RREF is the following>>>>>>"];
    Print[MatrixForm[A.variables],"=",MatrixForm[b]];
    Print["There is different solution for different value of the free variables."];
    Print["Setting free variable ", freeVariables," to zero gives"];
    variables=variables/.((t[#]->0)&/@Range[nFreeVariables]);
    Print[MatrixForm[A.variables],"=",MatrixForm[b]];
    Print["Therefore the final solution is "];
    Print[MatrixForm[x[#]&/@Range[nCols]],"=",MatrixForm[sol]]
    
   
]
(*version 3/10/2017. Original version*)
(*version 5/7/2022. Make it handle all cases*)
(*version 5/12/2022. Added frame around pivot as it moves*)

displayRREF[A_?(MatrixQ[#]&),b_?(VectorQ[#]&)]:=Module[
    {B,(*augmented*)nRows,nCols,nEquations,nVariables = Length@b,rref,pivotCols,matRank,augmentedRank},
    
    {nRows, nCols} = Dimensions[A];
    nEquations     = nRows;
   
    If[nEquations != nVariables, Return["Size of b vector is not the same as number of rows in the matrix",Module]];
   
    matRank   = MatrixRank[A];
    B = Join[A,Transpose[{b}],2];
    
    Print["Augmented matrix is "];
    displayMatrix[B,True];

    augmentedRank = MatrixRank[B];

    If[matRank<augmentedRank, (*Case No solution*)
         Print["System is not consistent, no solution exist. Try using least squares."]
    ,
        (*we must have rank A == rank[A|b]  -- system is consistent. It can have*)
        (*infinite solutions or one unique solution*)
        If[matRank == nCols, 
             If[nCols == nRows, (*square. case A*)
                  Print["System is consistent. One unique solution"];
                  {rref,pivotCols} = displayRREF[B,True];
                  
                  If[MatrixRank[A]!=Length[pivotCols], (*Verify*)
                      Print["Internal Error detected. Pivot columns not same as Rank. Please report bug"]
                  ,
                      Print["Solution  vector is ", MatrixForm[rref[[All, nCols + 1]]]]
                  ]
            ,
                Print["Internal Error detected. matRank != nCols but not square. "]
            ]
       ,
            (*-- rank A  < N. Case C *)
            Print["System is consistent but infinite solutions."];
            {rref,pivotCols} = displayRREF[B,True];
            makeSolutionSpecialCase[rref[[All,1;;nCols]],rref[[All,nCols+1]],pivotCols]
      ] 
   ]
]
makeNiceMatrix[mat_?MatrixQ,pivot_List,dashed_?BooleanQ]:=Module[{g,nRow,nCol},
    {nRow,nCol} = Dimensions[mat];
   (*g=Grid[mat,Dividers->{dashPosition->{Red,Dashed}},Background->{None,None,{pivot->Pink}}];*)
   If[dashed,
       g = Grid[mat,Dividers->{nCol->{Red,Dashed}},Frame->{None,None,{pivot->True}},Background->LightOrange]
   ,
       g = Grid[mat,Frame->{None,None,{pivot->True}}]
   ];
   MatrixForm[{{g}}]
]
(*thanks to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60613/how-to-add-a-vertical-line-to-a-matrix*)
(*makes a dash line inside Matrix*)
Format[matWithDiv[n_,opts:OptionsPattern[Grid]][m_?MatrixQ]]:=MatrixForm[{{Grid[m,opts,Dividers->{n->{Red,Dashed}}]}}];
```

---

### OLD ANSWER (do not use any more. Above is newer version)

Updated to Solve `Ax=b` and display all transformations to reduced Echelon form, and simplified the API. This now also prints the matrix inverse as by product, since it now uses an full augmented matrix.

The idea is to use `LUDecomposition` first to obtain the permutation rows used for pivoting. Once the order of the rows used is known, then forward elimination is used to generate Echelon form, then backward elimination is used to produce the final reduced echelon form and the solution vector.

Full augmented matrix is used so that the RHS of the augmented matrix will contain the matrix inverse at the end. Verified same inverse is produced as Mathematica `Inverse`. This only works on matrices that have non-zero determinant.

Here are some usage examples

### Example 1

```
(*solve Ax=b *)
mat = {{2, 7, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {3, 7, 9}};
b = {11, 2, -12};
displayRREF[mat, b]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Example 2

```
mat={{17,42,-36},{13,45,-34},{12,47,-35}};
b={213,226,197};
displayRREF[mat,b]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Example 3

```
mat={{5,2,18,4},{0,1,2,5},{4,1,12,6},{2,3,8,9}};
b={1,2,3,4};
displayRREF[mat,b]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Function

```
displayRREF[mat_?(MatrixQ[#] &), b_?(VectorQ[#] &)] := 
  Module[{i, j, multiplier, pivot, augmented, m = Length@mat, lu, p, c, tmp, inverse},
    (*version 3/10/2017*)
   
   (*check if matrix is singular.Per Daniel Lichtblau post seen Wolfram site*)
   (*this is better method than using Det*)
   If[MatrixQ[mat] && 
     MatrixRank[mat] == Length[mat] == Length[mat[[1]]] === False,
    Return["Sorry, but matrix is singular!"]
    ];
   
   If[Length@b != Length@mat,
    Return[
     "Size of b vector not the same as number of rows in A matrix"]
    ];
   
   {lu, p, c} = LUDecomposition[mat];
   tmp = lu SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; j >= i -> 1, {Length@mat, 
       Length@mat}];
   (*Print["Mathematica says Echelon form is ", MatrixForm@tmp];*)
   tmp = mat[[p, All]];
   (*Print["Mathematica says inverse Matrix is", MatrixForm@Inverse@
   mat];*)
   augmented = Join[mat, Transpose[{b}], 2];
   augmented = ArrayFlatten[{{augmented, IdentityMatrix[Length@tmp]}}];
   
   Print[">>>>>>Starting forward Gaussian elimination phase using ", 
    augmented[[All, 1 ;; m + 1]] // 
     matWithDiv[m + 1, Background -> LightOrange] , 
    MatrixForm[augmented[[All, m + 2 ;;]]]];
   Do[
    Print["pivot now is (", pivot, ",", pivot, ")" ];
    Do[
     multiplier = augmented[[j, pivot]]/augmented[[pivot, pivot]];
     Print["will now zero out element (", j, ",", pivot, 
      ") by subtracting ", multiplier, " times row ", pivot, 
      " from row ", j];
     augmented[[j, pivot ;;]] = 
      augmented[[j, pivot ;;]] - 
       multiplier*augmented[[pivot, pivot ;;]];
     Print[
      augmented[[All, 1 ;; m + 1]] // 
       matWithDiv[m + 1, Background -> LightOrange] , 
      MatrixForm[augmented[[All, m + 2 ;;]]]]
     , {j, pivot + 1, m}
     ]
    , {pivot, 1, m}
    ];
   
   Print[">>>>>>Starting backward elimination phase"];
   
   Do[
    Do[
     multiplier = augmented[[j, pivot]]/augmented[[pivot, pivot]];
     Print["will now zero out element (", j, ",", pivot, 
      ") by subtracting ", multiplier, " times row ", pivot, 
      " from row ", j];
     augmented[[j, pivot ;;]] = 
      augmented[[j, pivot ;;]] - 
       multiplier*augmented[[pivot, pivot ;;]];
     Print[
      augmented[[All, 1 ;; m + 1]] // 
       matWithDiv[m + 1, Background -> LightOrange] , 
      MatrixForm[augmented[[All, m + 2 ;;]]]]
     , {j, 1, pivot - 1}
     ]
    , {pivot, 2, m}
    ];
   
   Print[">>>>>>Starting Final phase, convert reduced echelon to     identity matrix"];
   Do[
    augmented[[j, ;;]] = augmented[[j, ;;]]/augmented[[j, j]]
    , {j, 1, m}
    ];
   
   Print[augmented[[All, 1 ;; m + 1]] // 
     matWithDiv[m + 1, Background -> LightOrange] , 
    MatrixForm[augmented[[All, m + 2 ;;]]]];
   (*flip at inverse Matrix now using p from LUDecomposition, 
   but using column wise*)
   Print["Inverse Matrix is ", 
    MatrixForm[ augmented[[All, m + 2 ;;]] ]];
   Print["Solution  vector is ", MatrixForm[augmented[[All, m + 1]]]]
   ];

(*thanks to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60613/how-to-add-a-vertical-line-to-a-matrix*)
(*makes a dash line inside Matrix*)
Format[matWithDiv[n_, opts : OptionsPattern[Grid]][m_?MatrixQ]] := 
  MatrixForm[{{Grid[m, opts, Dividers -> {n -> {Red, Dashed}}]}}];
```

Comment: Is there any way to get to this to work with a singular matrix as RREF certainly works for the augmented system? mat = {{1, -2, 4, 3, 2}, {-7, 14, -28, -12, -23}, {4, -8, 12, 12, 8}, {-3, 6, -4, -1, -14}}; b = {2, 4, 18, -10};
displayRREF[mat, b]

Comment: @Moo Yes, it is possible. But just a matter to getting the time to do it as I am busy with other things. I hope to be able to do that sometime in the future.

Comment: @Moo I've updated it to handle all cases. Any bugs please let me know.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this: mat = {{1, -2, 4, 3, 2}, {-7, 14, -28, -12, -23}, {4, -8, 12, 12, 
   8}, {-3, 6, -4, -1, -14}}; b = {2, 4, 18, -10}; displayRREF[mat, b]. it worked perfectly Thank you for updating it! (+1). By the way, i think it is great idea to make this a Resource Function!

Comment: @Nasser Hi! I want to limit the matrix to RREF by adding a multiple of one row to another row instead of column transformation and multiple of the row itself. If RREF cannot be achieved by this method, "Impossible" will be returned. How should I modify your code? thank you!

Comment: @lotus2019 sorry but I am not able to understand your question. when you say **instead of column transformation and multiple of the row itself** where is this done in the code? There is no column transformation?. RREF uses the standard algorithm as described in many linear algebra books. If you could explain more what is it you want, may be with an example or link, that will help as now I do not understand what is the change needed.

Comment: @Nasser  See my question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275558/factorize-a-matrix-into-the-product-of-several-matrices-of-specified-form. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The following answer is a contribution to enrich Nasser's code a little more:

```
NiceMatrixExtended[mat_?MatrixQ, pivot_?VectorQ] /; 
  Length[pivot] == 2 := 
 Module[{g, nRow, nCol, highlightedMat}, {nRow, nCol} = Dimensions[mat];
  (*A version of the matrix with the pivot highlighted using Item*)
  highlightedMat = mat;
  highlightedMat[[pivot[[1]], pivot[[2]]]] = 
  Item[mat[[pivot[[1]], pivot[[2]]]], Background -> LightBlue];
  g = Grid[highlightedMat, Background -> LightYellow, 
  Dividers -> {{nCol - nRow -> Directive[Red, Dashed, Thickness[1.5]], 
  nCol - nRow + 1 -> Directive[Red, Dashed, Thickness[1.5]]}}];
  MatrixForm[{{g}}]]
```

Testing `NiceMatrixExtended`:

```
system = {5 w + 2 x + 3 y - 6 z == 31, w + x - y - 4 z == 2, 
          2 w - x + 7 y - 5 z == 16, 3 w + 3 x + 2 y - 5 z == 23};
vars = {x, y, z, w};

(*Extended Augmented System Matrix*)
asys = {{2, 3, -6, 5, 31, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, -1, -4, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 
        {-1, 7, -5, 2, 16, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {3, 2, -5, 3, 23, 0, 0, 0, 1}};
NiceMatrixExtended[asys, {1, 1}]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv0gQ.png