# Parameter dependent linear independence check

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a rectangular matrix $M(x)$ depending on a real parameter $x$. I want to find out for which $x$ are the columns of $M(x)$ linearly dependent (or equivalently, when $M(x)$ has a nontrivial kernel). I thought about using NullSpace as in

```
NullSpace[M[x]]
```

but it stubbornly outputs an empty vector, I don't think it's able to tell me when there are nontrivial solutions. If for some reason I know of a solution $x_0$, `NullSpace[M[x0]]` outputs the correct nullspace, but how do I find $x_0$? If $M$ was square I could simply solve $\mathrm {Det}(M(x))=0$, but I don't have such luck.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can try to do a numerical search, otherwise you need a symbolic representation of your nullspace that can be solved for solutions

Comment: @b3m2a1 Hi, thanks for the comment, I'm only interested in analytical solutions unless it's impossible. What do you mean by symbolic representation of the NullSpace? Is there a way to have a symbolic representation beyond $M(x)=0$? The NullSpace might have different dimensions for various values of $x$.

Comment: I mean that it seems from the code like you want to know the null space in general for any arbitrary value of `x`, which is equivalent to having an analytic form for it. You might want to approach this from some other perspective at least to get some insights, say via the pseudo-inverse or something.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6179478) might help. Also I think I have seen another related question and will try to find it.

Comment: [This one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139606/find-elementary-matrices-that-produce-rref) shows a general method. Augment on the right with an identity matrix. Row reduce. Check for denominators. Where they vanish gives necessary conditions for drops in the matrix rank.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau hi! Thanks! Your comment seems quite interesting, but I don't understand what you mean. The link you've given lets you do row reduction showing steps, how does it help me? If I try to simply to RowReduce on my matrix it doesn't work (behaves similarly to NullSpace)

Comment: (1) Recall I stated you should augment with an identity matrix. Did you do that prior to using `RowReduce`? (2) If you edit the post to provide an explicit example, I might be able to demonstrate what I had in mind.