# How can I show the calculation of the determinant of a matrix step by step?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, wolfram-alpha-queries

I would like to emulate what Wolfram Alpha does in Mathematica.
Can you help me?

```
WolframAlpha["Det[{{3,-1,4,6},{2,-3,1,13},{4,-2,7,12},{0,-1,0,9}}]",
             {{"Result", 2}, "Content"}, PodStates -> {"Result__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

Comment: [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139615) can be modified a bit so that it computes the determinant step-by-step.

Comment: What do you mean by "step-by-step calculation of determinant"? The command from the question works in 12.2. The matrix is reduced to the upper-triangular form preserving the value of its determinant and then its deteminant equals the product of the diagonal elements.

Comment: @user, I interpreted it as saying that the OP wants to see an explicit re-implementation of what Alpha does to compute a determinant step-by-step.

Comment: Unfortunately, `WolframAlpha["Det[RandomReal[{-1,1},{4,4}]]", {{"Result", 2}, 
  "Content"}, PodStates -> {"Result__Step-by-step solution"}]` performs "(step-by-step solution unavailable)". There is a room for an improvement in this direction.

Comment: @MarcoB: W|A says exactly the same.