# Avoid condensing and use original terms in result of RowReduce

Tags: matrix, output

*[Note: The given 2 solutions deal only with a simple example but not with the real problem]*

Can I force MMA to use original expressions in a result of `RowReduce` instead of displaying only the condensed result?

For better understanding I give a simple example with `Solve` instead of `RowReduce`:

```
Solve[5x-2==3,x]
x->1
```

I want a result that includes original terms, e.g.

```
x->(3+2)/5
```

My code with `RowReduce`:

```
RowReduce[{{-1/(
     2 Sqrt[2]) (√(Sqrt[(s6^2 (s1^2 + s3^2) + 
            s4^2 (s1^2 + s5^2) + s2^2 (s3^2 + s5^2))^2 - 
          4 (s1^2 s3^2 + s1^2 s5^2 + s3^2 s5^2) (s2^2 s4^2 + 
             s2^2 s6^2 + s4^2 s6^2)] + s6^2 (s1^2 + s3^2) + 
         s4^2 (s1^2 + s5^2) + s2^2 (s3^2 + s5^2))), 0, 0, (s1 s4)/2, 
   0, -(1/2) (s1 s6)}, {0, -1/(
     2 Sqrt[2]) (√(Sqrt[(s6^2 (s1^2 + s3^2) + 
            s4^2 (s1^2 + s5^2) + s2^2 (s3^2 + s5^2))^2 - 
          4 (s1^2 s3^2 + s1^2 s5^2 + s3^2 s5^2) (s2^2 s4^2 + 
             s2^2 s6^2 + s4^2 s6^2)] + s6^2 (s1^2 + s3^2) + 
         s4^2 (s1^2 + s5^2) + s2^2 (s3^2 + s5^2))), -(1/2) (s2 s3), 
   0, (s2 s5)/2, 
   0}, {0, -(1/2) (s2 s3), -1/(
     2 Sqrt[2]) (√(Sqrt[(s6^2 (s1^2 + s3^2) + 
            s4^2 (s1^2 + s5^2) + s2^2 (s3^2 + s5^2))^2 - 
          4 (s1^2 s3^2 + s1^2 s5^2 + s3^2 s5^2) (s2^2 s4^2 + 
             s2^2 s6^2 + s4^2 s6^2)] + s6^2 (s1^2 + s3^2) + 
         s4^2 (s1^2 + s5^2) + s2^2 (s3^2 + s5^2))), 0, 0, (s3 s6)/
   2}, {(s1 s4)/2, 0, 
   0, -1/(2 Sqrt[
      2]) (√(Sqrt[(s6^2 (s1^2 + s3^2) + s4^2 (s1^2 + s5^2) + 
            s2^2 (s3^2 + s5^2))^2 - 
          4 (s1^2 s3^2 + s1^2 s5^2 + s3^2 s5^2) (s2^2 s4^2 + 
             s2^2 s6^2 + s4^2 s6^2)] + s6^2 (s1^2 + s3^2) + 
         s4^2 (s1^2 + s5^2) + s2^2 (s3^2 + s5^2))), -(1/2) (s4 s5), 
   0}, {0, (s2 s5)/2, 
   0, -(1/2) (s4 s5), -1/(
     2 Sqrt[2]) (√(Sqrt[(s6^2 (s1^2 + s3^2) + 
            s4^2 (s1^2 + s5^2) + s2^2 (s3^2 + s5^2))^2 - 
          4 (s1^2 s3^2 + s1^2 s5^2 + s3^2 s5^2) (s2^2 s4^2 + 
             s2^2 s6^2 + s4^2 s6^2)] + s6^2 (s1^2 + s3^2) + 
         s4^2 (s1^2 + s5^2) + s2^2 (s3^2 + s5^2))), 
   0}, {-(1/2) (s1 s6), 0, (s3 s6)/2, 0, 
   0, -1/(2 Sqrt[
      2]) (√(Sqrt[(s6^2 (s1^2 + s3^2) + s4^2 (s1^2 + s5^2) + 
            s2^2 (s3^2 + s5^2))^2 - 
          4 (s1^2 s3^2 + s1^2 s5^2 + s3^2 s5^2) (s2^2 s4^2 + 
             s2^2 s6^2 + s4^2 s6^2)] + s6^2 (s1^2 + s3^2) + 
         s4^2 (s1^2 + s5^2) + s2^2 (s3^2 + s5^2)))}}]
```

In the solution I would like to see all roots as they appear in the above expression so that I can easily associate the terms.

This [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/258613/69288) about `RowReduce` does not work in my case.

Comment: I don't think can be achieved for `Solve` without rewriting `Solve` by yourself. Also, you should specify more precisely what you mean by "any other operation" because there are thousands of different "operations" in Mathematica, working very differently from each other. You probably have some particular problem in mind – show it explicitly.

Comment: It is of no use if you give some completely different example with `Solve` when you actually want a solution for `RowReduce`. Show the _actual_ problem you have. It can be simplified (like using a smaller, simpler matrix), but not completely different.

Comment: @granularbastard, then show a _smaller_ matrix. If you have ``mat``, post ``mat[[1;;2, 1;;2]]``, or make up a simpler matrix! Stop other people wasting time, and answering your question by using `Solve`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = 5 x - 2 == 3;

eqn2 = eqn /. n_Integer :> Sign[n]*ToString[Abs[n]];

sol = Solve[eqn2, x][[1]]
```

[image]

```
sol2 = sol /. str_String :> ToExpression[str]

{x -> 1}
```

**EDIT:** For a slightly more complicated equation

```
eqn = 5 x - 2 == 3 x^2;

eqn2 = eqn /. a_Integer*x^n_. :> Sign[a]*ToString[a]*x^n;

sol = Solve[eqn2, x]
```

[image]

```
sol2 = sol /. str_String :> ToExpression[str]

(* {{x -> 2/3}, {x -> 1}} *)

eqn /. sol2

(* {True, True} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to need to decide ahead of time which parts of your equation are the terms in which you want your solution to appear. Then you can use dummy variables for those terms. You will also need some way to stop evaluation of your final expression, and some form of Hold* is appropriate for that.

For example

```
eq1 = a x - b == c;
sols1 = Solve[eq1, x];
MapAt[HoldForm, sols1, {All, All, 2}] /. {a -> 5, b -> 2, c -> 3}
```

`{{x -> (2 + 3)/5}}` (the HoldForm is there, just suppressed in the display).

Or

```
eq2 = a x - b == c x^2;
sols2 = Solve[eq, x];
MapAt[HoldForm, sols2, {All, All, 2}] /. {a -> 5, b -> 2, c -> 3}
```

`{{x ->-1/2*(-1*5 + Sqrt[5^2 - 4*2*3])/3}, {x ->(5 + Sqrt[5^2 - 4*2*3])/(2*3)}}`

Or even just apply the HoldForm from the beginning to the terms you want to preserve:

```
eq3 = HoldForm[5] x - HoldForm[2] == HoldForm[3] x^2;
sols3 = Solve[eq3, x]
```

(Same result in appearance, but the HoldForm is in different places.)

Comment: I don't know what result you want, so I don't know. At the time I posted this answer, there was no RowReduce example, so you've moved the goalposts. But the principle is that to get the structure you want in the result you need to determine which symbols to hold. If that doesn't work with RowReduce, or if it just doesn't work in your context, well, then, it doesn't work. Sorry. I answered the question that was originally asked.

Comment: At the time of asking the question it is not clear if a solution for a simple example can be applied in general.

Comment: The burden is on the asker to ask a well-formed and relevant question. The burden is not on the answerer to guess what generalizations the asker is keeping secret.

Comment: The original question states "My question concerns not only `Solve` but any operation." This also includes `RowReduce`. Actually I thought there is an option that works for any operation.