# How do I solve a system of equations through Gaussian elimination using Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

**I have absolutely no experience using Mathematica or similar packages, so please bear in mind with me.
I am an IB student that has gotten themselves a copy of Mathematica for the purpose of simply performing Gaussian elimination, a method that I am largely unfamiliar with (as it is not part of our syllabus).**
[image: System of Equations]

I have the above system of equations that I would like to solve, and I have the following numerical values:
[image: Coordinates]
[image: Radii]

I would like to ask, how can I apply Gaussian elimination in Mathematica to obtain the following numbers, through solving system S?

[image: Results]

Again, I want to mention that I know little about Gaussian elimination and even less about Mathematica, which is the reason I came to this exchange. Any help would be really greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

---

```
{
 2 (x2 - x1) x + 2 (y2 - y1) y + 2 (z2 - z1) z == r1^2 - x1^2 - r2^2 + x2^2,
 2 (x3 - x1) x + 2 (y3 - y1) y + 2 (z3 - z1) z == r1^2 - x1^2 - r3^2 + x3^2,
 2 (x4 - x1) x + 2 (y4 - y1) y + 2 (z4 - z1) z == r1^2 - x1^2 - r4^2 + x4^2,
 x1 == 2088202.299, x3 == 35606984.591,
 y1 == -11757191.37, y3 == 94447027.237,
 z1 == 25391471.881, z3 == 9101378.572,
 x2 == 11092568.240, x4 == 3966929.048,
 y2 == -14198201.090, y4 == 7362851.831,
 z2 == 21471165.950, z4 == 26388447.172,
 r1 == 23204698.51, r2 == 21585835.37,
 r3 == 31364260.01, r4 == 24966798.73
}
```

Comment: [`Solve[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) is what you want; look at the second example in the linked doc page. The only tricky thing here is that you can't use subscripts here, so you would need to write e.g. the first equation as `2 (x2 - x1) x + 2 (y2 - y1) y + 2 (z2 - z1) z == r1^2 - x1^2 - r2^2 + x2^2`.

Comment: Omit the commas in the number.

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to use Gaussian elimination (HW requirement) then you can do the following:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqs = {2 (x2 - x1) x + 2 (y2 - y1) y + 2 (z2 - z1) z == 
    r1^2 - x1^2 - r2^2 + x2^2, 
   2 (x3 - x1) x + 2 (y3 - y1) y + 2 (z3 - z1) z == 
    r1^2 - x1^2 - r3^2 + x3^2, 
   2 (x4 - x1) x + 2 (y4 - y1) y + 2 (z4 - z1) z == 
    r1^2 - x1^2 - r4^2 + x4^2};
par = {x1 -> 2088202.299, x3 -> 35606984.591, y1 -> -11757191.37, 
   y3 -> 94447027.237, z1 -> 25391471.881, z3 -> 9101378.572, 
   x2 -> 11092568.240, x4 -> 3966929.048, y2 -> -14198201.090, 
   y4 -> 7362851.831, z2 -> 21471165.950, z4 -> 26388447.172, 
   r1 -> 23204698.51, r2 -> 21585835.37, r3 -> 31364260.01, 
   r4 -> 24966798.73};
eqs = eqs /. par
vars = {x, y, z};
{b, A} = Normal@CoefficientArrays[eqs, vars];
Row[{"we need to solve ", MatrixForm@A . MatrixForm@vars == MatrixForm[-b]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you can do Gaussian elimination using [displayRREF](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139606/find-elementary-matrices-that-produce-rref)  which gives

```
displayRREF[A, -b]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To verify, you can use `NSolve` as suggested, or use

```
 LinearSolve[A, -b] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Typing in your equations, then using `NSolve`:

```
eqs = {
   2 (x2 - x1) x + 2 (y2 - y1) y + 2 (z2 - z1) z == r1^2 - x1^2 - r2^2 + x2^2,
   2 (x3 - x1) x + 2 (y3 - y1) y + 2 (z3 - z1) z == r1^2 - x1^2 - r3^2 + x3^2,
   2 (x4 - x1) x + 2 (y4 - y1) y + 2 (z4 - z1) z == r1^2 - x1^2 - r4^2 + x4^2,
   x1 == 2088202.299,   x3 == 35606984.591,   y1 == -11757191.37,
   y3 == 94447027.237,   z1 == 25391471.881,   z3 == 9101378.572,
   x2 == 11092568.240,   x4 == 3966929.048,   y2 == -14198201.090,
   y4 == 7362851.831,   z2 == 21471165.950,   z4 == 26388447.172,
   r1 == 23204698.51,   r2 == 21585835.37,   r3 == 31364260.01,
   r4 == 24966798.73
};

NSolve[eqs]

(* Out: {
 {r1 -> 2.32047*10^7, r2 -> 2.15858*10^7, r3 -> 3.13643*10^7, 
  r4 -> 2.49668*10^7, x1 -> 2.0882*10^6, x2 -> 1.10926*10^7, 
  x3 -> 3.5607*10^7, y1 -> -1.17572*10^7, y3 -> 9.4447*10^7, 
  x4 -> 3.96693*10^6, y4 -> 7.36285*10^6, z1 -> 2.53915*10^7, 
  z4 -> 2.63884*10^7, z3 -> 9.10138*10^6, y2 -> -1.41982*10^7, 
  z2 -> 2.14712*10^7,
  x -> -2.99306*10^6, y -> 1880.12, z -> -3.12609*10^7}
} *)
```

You will notice that the results for $x$, $y$, $z$ are similar, but not identical, to those you proposed.