# Perform row transformation only in RREF: Factorize a matrix into the product of $\boldsymbol{I}+k \boldsymbol{E}_{i j}$

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Before explaining this problem, I will list and explain the matrix symbols used. The matrix obtained from the identity matrix through an elementary row (column) transformation is called the **Elementary Matrix**.

**There are only three types of** **Elementary Matrices**:
$\boldsymbol{P}(j, i(k)), \boldsymbol{P}(i, j), \boldsymbol{P}(i(c))$, where $c \neq 0$.
Let ***A*** be an s * n matrix, and its row vector group is $\gamma_1, \gamma_2, \cdots, \gamma_s$,

1. Left multiplying ***A*** by ***P***(j, i (k)) is equivalent to adding the k-fold of row i of ***A*** to row j, and the remaining rows remain unchanged.

***P***(j,i(k)) ***A***=$\left(\begin{array}{ccccccc}1 & & & & & & \\ & \ddots & & & & & \\ & & 1 & & & & \\ & & \vdots & \ddots & & & \\ & & k & \cdots & 1 & & \\ & & & & & \ddots & \\ & & & & & & 1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}\gamma_1 \\ \gamma_2 \\ \vdots \\ \gamma_s\end{array}\right)$$=\left(\begin{array}{c}\gamma_1 \\ \vdots \\ \gamma_i \\ \vdots \\ k \gamma_i+\gamma_j \\ \vdots \\ \gamma_s\end{array}\right)$

2. Left multiplying ***A*** by ***P*** (i, j) is equivalent to swapping row i of ***A*** with row j, and the remaining rows remain unchanged;
3. Left Multiply ***A*** by ***P*** (i (c)) ($c \neq 0$), which is equivalent to multiplying the ith row of ***A*** by c, and the remaining rows remain unchanged.

**The following is a question in the textbook:**

1. Let ***A*** be a square matrix of order 2. Please prove that if `Det[A]==1`, then ***A*** can be expressed as the product of ***P***(j, i (k)) (that is, ***A*** can represent the product of a matrix shaped like $\boldsymbol{I}+k \boldsymbol{E}_{i j}$, where $i \neq j$).
2. Let ***A*** be a square matrix of order n (n>=2). Please prove that if `Det[A]==1`, then ***A*** can be expressed as the product of ***P***(j, i (k)).

Where $\boldsymbol{I}$ is the **Identity Matrix** `IdentityMatrix[2]`.

Where a matrix with only one element being 1 and all other elements being 0 is called a **Basic Matrix**. The **Basic Matrix** with (i, j) element 1 is recorded as $\boldsymbol{E}_{i j}$. The MMA code of the basic matrix $\boldsymbol{E}_{i j}$ (`mE`) is:

```
mE[n_Integer?Positive][i_Integer, j_Integer] /; 
  0 < i <= n && 0 < j <= n := 
 Module[{m = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}]}, m[[i, j]] = 1; m]
```

Where, the MMA code of 2-order random square matrix ***A*** (`mA`) with `Det[mA]==1` is:

```
det = Module[{i}, 
   Sequence @@ (i /. Solve[Det[{{#1, #2}, {#3, i}}] == 1, i]) &];
candidates = 
  Apply[{##, det@##} &, RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {10000, 3}], 2] // 
   Quiet;
listR = RandomChoice[
   Select[candidates, Abs@Last@# <= 10 && IntegerQ@Last@# &]];

mA = Partition[listR, 2]
```

**I want to use MMA code to achieve the following points:**

1. Modify @ Nasser's program `displayRREF` ([Find Elementary Matrices that produce RREF](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139606/find-elementary-matrices-that-produce-rref/139615?noredirect=1#comment688056_139615)) to ***perform row transformation P(j,i(r)) only*** on 2-order square random matrix ***A*** (`mA`) with `Det[mA]==1`, i.e.***P***(j,i(r))***P***(l,k(s))...***P***(q,p(t)) ***A***, where $i \neq j$, $k \neq l$... $p \neq q$. Thus, the elementary matrix ***P*** (j, i (r)), ***P***(l,k(s))... ***P***(q,p(t)) can be found.
2. Factorize 2-order random square matrix ***A*** (`mA`) with `Det[mA]==1` into  ($\boldsymbol{I}+k \boldsymbol{E}_{i j}$)($\boldsymbol{I}+l \boldsymbol{E}_{s t}$)...($\boldsymbol{I}+m \boldsymbol{E}_{u v}$),  where $i \neq j$, $s \neq t$... $u \neq v$.
3. Factorize n-order (n>=2) random square matrix ***A*** (`mA`) with `Det[mA]==1` into ***P***(j,i(r))***P***(l,k(s))...***P***(q,p(t)),  where $i \neq j$, $k \neq l$... $p \neq q$.

Thanks!