# Show steps in finding the reduced row echelon form of a symbolic matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I would like to figure out a way to see the row operations `RowReduce` uses to arrive at the reduced row echelon form of a symbolic square matrix.

Solutions that show the steps were already given in this forum ([post1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/258613/69288), [post2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139615/69288)), however they work only for numerical matrices, but not for symbolic matrices.

**Example**

Especially I am looking for the `RowReduce` steps for the following $6\times 6$ matrix `mat`, that is defined by

```
m={{0,0,0,s1*s4/2,0,-s1*s6/2},
   {0,0,-s2*s3/2,0,s2*s5/2,0},
   {0,-s2*s3/2,0,0,0,s3*s6/2},
   {s1*s4/2,0,0,0,-s4*s5/2,0},
   {0,s2*s5/2,0,-s4*s5/2,0,0},
   {-s1*s6/2,0,s3*s6/2,0,0,0}};
q=(s1^2*s3^2+s1^2*s5^2+s3^2*s5^2)*(s2^2*s4^2+s2^2*s6^2+s4^2*s6^2);
p=s2^2*(s3^2+s5^2)+s4^2*(s1^2+s5^2)+s6^2*(s1^2+s3^2);
l=Sqrt[1/8*(p+Sqrt[p^2-4*q])];
mat=m-l*IdentityMatrix[6];

RowReduce[mat]
```

The variables of `mat`are $(s1,\ldots ,s6) \in \mathbb{R_{>0}}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update July 17, 2023**

> Which line to adapt so that no matrices during the row reduce steps
> are displayed?

Here is a version which does that. [here](https://12000.org/my_notes/rref/index.htm)

The default is to display the matrices. If you do not want that, then call with `False` as second argument. Here is screen shot showing this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To show the matrices again, simply remove the `False`, like this

```
{result, pivots} = displayRREF[mat];
```

**Original answer**

This is below is modification of code from [Find Elementary Matrices that produce RREF](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139606/find-elementary-matrices-that-produce-rref)  so now it can work with symbolic entries.

I tested it on few small symbolic matrices and it gives same result as Mathematica. This does forward elimination followed by backward elimination to obtain the Reduced Row Echelon Form which will be just a diagonal matrix for square matrix.

The square matrix is much easier to do. I also tested on your matrix and it also gave same result as Mathematica. But too large to post it here.

Here are some usage examples of smaller size.

### Example 1

```
mat = {{3, a}, {2, b}}
displayRREF[mat]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Example 2

```
mat = {{s, Sqrt[s], 3, 10, s^2}, {1, s, 2*s, 10, 1}, {0, 2, 3, 10, 
    s^9}, {1/s, 5, 3, 8, 2 + s}};
MatrixForm[mat]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
{result, pivots} = displayRREF[mat]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to Mathematica's results

```
 (mmaResult = RowReduce[mat]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Verified same:

```
 (result - mmaResult) // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Code is written in code cell. So it might get messed up when copying to input cell. So I also put the notebook [here](https://12000.org/tmp/RREF_april_29_2023/RREF_v_april_29_2023.nb)

```
(*Version April 29, 2023 of displayRREF*)
(*bug reports are welcome*)
 displayMatrix[A_?(MatrixQ[#]&),dashed_?BooleanQ]:= If[dashed,displayMatrix[A,Last@Dimensions[A]],Print[MatrixForm[A]]]
 displayMatrix[A_?(MatrixQ[#]&),nCols_Integer]:= Print[A[[All,1;;nCols]]//matWithDiv[nCols,Background->LightOrange]]
displayRREF[Ain_?(MatrixQ[#]&),dashed_:False]:=Module[
  {multiplier,j,i,pivotRow,pivotCol,nRows,nCols,p,tmp,startAgain,A=Ain,n,m,pivotsFound={},keepEliminating,nIter,entry},
    displayMatrix[A,dashed];
    {nRows,nCols} = Dimensions[A];
    
    keepEliminating=True;
    
    n=1; m=1;
    nIter = 0;
    While[keepEliminating,
        nIter++;
        If[nIter>100, (*safe guard*)
             Return["Internal error. Something went wrong. Or very large system?",Module]
        ];
        
        If[dashed && m==nCols,
             keepEliminating=False 
        ,
             Print["Pivot is A(",n,",",m,")"];
             Print@makeNiceMatrix[A,{n,m},dashed];
             If[A[[n,m]] =!= 0,
                  If[A[[n,m]] =!= 1,
                       A[[n,All]] = A[[n,All]]/A[[n,m]];
                       A=Simplify[A];
                       Print["Making the pivot 1 using using row(",n,")= row(",n,")/A(",n,",",m,")"]
                       (*Print@makeNiceMatrix[A,{n,m},dashed]*)
                 ];
                 If[n<nRows,
                       Do[
                            If[A[[j,m]] =!= 0,
                                  multiplier = A[[j,m]]/A[[n,m]];
                                  Print["Zeroing out element A(",j,",",m,") using row(",j,")=",multiplier,"*row(",n,")-row(",j,")"];
                                  A[[j,m;;]] = A[[j,m;;]] - multiplier*A[[n,m;;]];
                                  A=Simplify[A];
                                  Print@makeNiceMatrix[A,{n,m},dashed];
                            ]
                       ,{j,n+1,nRows}
                       ];
                  ];
                  pivotsFound = AppendTo[pivotsFound,{n,m}];
                  If[n==nRows,
                      keepEliminating=False
                  ,
                      n++;
                      If[m<nCols,m++]   
                  ]
            ,
                  (*pivot is zero*)
                  Print["Pivot is zero"];
                  (*Print@makeNiceMatrix[A,{n,m},dashed];*)
                  If[n==nRows&&m==nCols, keepEliminating=False
                  ,
                       (*pivot is zero. If we can find non-zero pivot row below, then exchange rows*)
                       If[n<nRows,
                             p = FirstPosition[A[[n+1;;,m]],_?(# =!=0)&];
                             If[ p===Missing["NotFound"]|| Length[p]==0,
                                  If[m<nCols,
                                      m++
                                  ,
                                      keepEliminating=False
                                  ]
                             ,
                                  (*found non zero pivot below. Exchange rows*)
                                  tmp = A[[n,All]];
                                  A[[n,All]] = A[[First[p]+n,All]];
                                  A[[First[p]+n,All]] = tmp;
                                  A=Simplify[A];
                                  Print["Exchanging row(",n,") and row(",First[p]+n,")"];
                                  Print@makeNiceMatrix[A,{n,m},dashed]
                            ]
                      ,
                            If[m<nCols,
                                  m++
                            ,
                                  keepEliminating=False
                            ]
                      ]
                  ]
             ]
        ]
    ];
         
    
    (*pivotsFound = DeleteDuplicates[pivotsFound];*)
    Print@makeNiceMatrix[A,{n,m},dashed];
    Print[">>>>>>Starting backward elimination phase. The pivots are ",pivotsFound];
    Do[ 
        pivotRow=First@entry;
        pivotCol=Last@entry;
       
        If[pivotRow>1,
            Do[
                 If[ A[[i,pivotCol]] =!= 0,
                      Print["Zeroing out element A(",i,",",pivotCol,") using row(",i,")=row(",i,")-A(",i,",",pivotCol,")*row(",pivotRow,")"];
                      A[[i,;;]] = A[[i,;;]] - A[[i,pivotCol]]*A[[pivotRow,;;]];
                      A=Simplify[A];
                      Print@makeNiceMatrix[A,{pivotRow,pivotCol},dashed]
                 ]
            ,
            {i,pivotRow-1,1,-1} 
           ]
        ]
        ,
        {entry,pivotsFound}    
   ];
   
   {A,pivotsFound[[All,2]]}
]
makeSolutionSpecialCase[A_?(MatrixQ[#]&),b_?(VectorQ[#]&),pivotCols_List]:=Module[
   {nRows,nCols,nLeadingVariables,nFreeVariables,n,m,k,variables={},eq,freeVariables,sol={}},
   
    Print["Pivot columns are ",MatrixForm[pivotCols]];
    
    ClearAll[x,t]; (*did not make them local, to prevent $ from showing in print*)
    {nRows,nCols} = Dimensions[A];
    nLeadingVariables = Length[pivotCols];
    nFreeVariables =  nCols-nLeadingVariables;    
    Print["There are ",nLeadingVariables," leading variables and ",nFreeVariables," free variables. These are "];
    
    Array[t, nFreeVariables];
    Array[x, nCols];
    
    m=0;k=0;
    Do[
        If[Not[MemberQ[pivotCols,n]],
            m++;
            Print[x[n]," is a free variable. Let ",x[n],"=",t[m]];
            AppendTo[variables,t[m]];
            AppendTo[sol,0]
        ,
            Print[x[n]," is a leading variable"];
            AppendTo[variables,x[n]];
            AppendTo[sol,b[[++k]]]
        ]
    ,{n,1,nCols}
    ];
    
    freeVariables=(t[#]&/@Range[nFreeVariables]);
    Print["Hence the system after RREF is the following>>>>>>"];
    Print[MatrixForm[A.variables],"=",MatrixForm[b]];
    Print["There is different solution for different value of the free variables."];
    Print["Setting free variable ", freeVariables," to zero gives"];
    variables=variables/.((t[#]->0)&/@Range[nFreeVariables]);
    Print[MatrixForm[A.variables],"=",MatrixForm[b]];
    Print["Therefore the final solution is "];
    Print[MatrixForm[x[#]&/@Range[nCols]],"=",MatrixForm[sol]]
    
   
]
(*version 3/10/2017. Original version*)
(*version 5/7/2022. Make it handle all cases*)
(*version 5/12/2022. Added frame around pivot as it moves*)

displayRREF[A_?(MatrixQ[#]&),b_?(VectorQ[#]&)]:=Module[
    {B,(*augmented*)nRows,nCols,nEquations,nVariables = Length@b,rref,pivotCols,matRank,augmentedRank},
    
    {nRows, nCols} = Dimensions[A];
    nEquations     = nRows;
   
    If[nEquations != nVariables, Return["Size of b vector is not the same as number of rows in the matrix",Module]];
   
    matRank   = MatrixRank[A];
    B = Join[A,Transpose[{b}],2];
    
    Print["Augmented matrix is "];
    displayMatrix[B,True];

    augmentedRank = MatrixRank[B];

    If[matRank<augmentedRank, (*Case No solution*)
         Print["System is not consistent, no solution exist. Try using least squares."]
    ,
        (*we must have rank A == rank[A|b]  -- system is consistent. It can have*)
        (*infinite solutions or one unique solution*)
        If[matRank == nCols, 
             If[nCols == nRows, (*square. case A*)
                  Print["System is consistent. One unique solution"];
                  {rref,pivotCols} = displayRREF[B,True];
                  
                  If[MatrixRank[A]!=Length[pivotCols], (*Verify*)
                      Print["Internal Error detected. Pivot columns not same as Rank. Please report bug"]
                  ,
                      Print["Solution  vector is ", MatrixForm[rref[[All, nCols + 1]]]]
                  ]
            ,
                Print["Internal Error detected. matRank != nCols but not square. "]
            ]
       ,
            (*-- rank A  < N. Case C *)
            Print["System is consistent but infinite solutions."];
            {rref,pivotCols} = displayRREF[B,True];
            makeSolutionSpecialCase[rref[[All,1;;nCols]],rref[[All,nCols+1]],pivotCols]
      ] 
   ]
]
makeNiceMatrix[mat_?MatrixQ,pivot_List,dashed_?BooleanQ]:=Module[{g,nRow,nCol},
    {nRow,nCol} = Dimensions[mat];
   (*g=Grid[mat,Dividers->{dashPosition->{Red,Dashed}},Background->{None,None,{pivot->Pink}}];*)
   If[dashed,
       g = Grid[mat,Dividers->{nCol->{Red,Dashed}},Frame->{None,None,{pivot->True}},Background->LightOrange]
   ,
       g = Grid[mat,Frame->{None,None,{pivot->True}}]
   ];
   MatrixForm[{{g}}]
]
(*thanks to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60613/how-to-add-a-vertical-line-to-a-matrix*)
(*makes a dash line inside Matrix*)
Format[matWithDiv[n_,opts:OptionsPattern[Grid]][m_?MatrixQ]]:=MatrixForm[{{Grid[m,opts,Dividers->{n->{Red,Dashed}}]}}];
```

Comment: Great Work! Which line to adapt so that no matrices during the row reduce steps are  displayed? Only the information about row operations shall be printed.

Comment: More comfortable would be if matrix display could be selected by a parameter in the function call

Comment: @granularbastard added flag, example shown at top and updated the notebook in the link.

Comment: Unclear how one should regard the result for symbolic matrices: one doesn't know a priori which entries are 0, or which linear combinations of entries (produced after normalizing pivot entry to 1 and then zeroing out below) are 0.

Comment: @murray yes, at school we only did RREF on matrices with numbers. But someone asked for this function to handle matrices with symbols also. So that is why. I myself only use RREF for matrices with numbers.

Answer (score 3):

I added one minor bug fix to Nasser's excellent code. In my testing, if the matrix has more rows than columns, it would continue eliminating even if it's run out of columns, e.g. treating the non-existent $A_{4,4}$ in a 4x3 matrix as a pivot. See below: [image: tall matrix bug]

Note that this doesn't seem to actually affect the result, however. In any case, my patch is simply or-ing `m==nCols` as an additional stopping condition to set the `keepEliminating` flag.

```
                  If[n==nRows || m==nCols,
                      keepEliminating=False
                  ,
                      n++;
                      m++   
                  ]
```

Of course, I don't have a full understanding of Nasser's code, so I'm not sure if any other changes are needed elsewhere to handle this case of $n>m$. Consider this just a bug report in that respect.

(I am aware that this should've been posted as a comment, not an answer, but as I'm just starting out on SE as poster, albit a long-time reader/user, I lack the necessary reputation... Feel free to delete this and/or incorporate into the main answer if appropriate. Thanks for understanding!)

Comment: Another (related?) minor bug: The steps of making the pivot 1 and zeroing out elements below it don't quite print in the right order, or have the right cell highlighted. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42WaF.png)

Comment: Could you please show the input Matrix you used in InputForm so I can try it? You show only an image and I am not sure what you used as initial input for the matrix. I see you have "." dots in there. Not sure what these are. If I can reproduce these, I will correct the code.

Comment: Certainly, my input matrix is `mat = {{-p1 . p4 + p2 . p4, -p1 . p4 + p3 . p4, 1 - p1 . p4}, {-p1 . p3 + p2 . p3, 1 - p1 . p3, -p1 . p3 + p3 . p4}, 
 {1 - p1 . p2, -p1 . p2 + p2 . p3, -p1 . p2 + p2 . p4}, {-1 + p1 . p2, -1 + p1 . p3, -1 + p1 . p4}}`. The "." dots are symbolic dot products, since `pi` represents vectors. For simplicity, I was still able to reproduce the behavior with `mat = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}`.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it. Needed to add `If[m<nCols,m++]` to check for columns also. I also fixed it in the notebook where I have the link to above. As for the use of DOT product, this is really meant for scalar type matrix input. I do not think you should have the input be dot product in the matrix, as I do not know how it will behave in that case. i.e. the matrix needs to be numerical or symbols. Anything else, no guarantee how it will behave.  THanks for reporting the problem.

Comment: Of course, thank you for investigating and fixing the bug. I just wanted to check whether a couple other things are intended behavior or other minor bugs. First, in the example usage [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paOgg.png) with a wide matrix, it prints the matrix right after "Making the pivot 1 using...", with the pivot highlighted. But with the tall (1 to 6) matrix I gave above, it skips printing the matrix after making a non-zero pivot 1, and before zeroing, see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIsXA.png). Perhaps a print matrix command was accidentally left commented?

Comment: Second, also seen in screenshot 2, is it necessary/valid to check whether A(3,2) is a pivot, after we just explicitly made it 0? I thought only if A(2,2) was 0 and not a pivot, would/should it look below and try to do a row-swap. It seems odd to look for another pivot in a column that already has one. The logic behind my attempted fix was to stop if it's reached the end of either dimension. (Don't get me wrong, I'm not at all confident my fix is logically/mathematically sound.) Anyway, it doesn't change the end result, but that extra step may be confusing for someone using this to learn RREF.

Comment: Regarding my use of the "." dot product, I think it was okay in this case because I'm essentially treating `pi.pj` as merely a symbol, since it equals a scalar, no different from `a` or `x`. Since my symbols `pi` are undefined, I guess Mathematica doesn't do anything with the dot.

Comment: A separate issue, which you alluded to in an earlier post's comment, is whether any given symbolic expression equals 0 and can't be a pivot. However, my own earlier testing (the testing that led me to this code in the first place) showed that Mathematica's built-in RREF doesn't account for that either in a symbolic matrix, row-reducing to all pivot columns even if there are values for the symbols that would make a pivot 0, and the matrix not full-rank, so I think your code is fine in that regard.

Comment: In fact, the reason I wanted all the steps was to find which exact step it could fail, namely when a pivot could be 0, and derive the condition on my symbols that would make it so. Your tool has been very helpful, even though so far I still haven't been able to derive a nice form for the condition that agrees algebraically with the condition I know "a priori" for my matrix to not be full rank.

Comment: The echelon form is independent of the path taken in the reduction. So if the goal is to obtain correctness conditions, one can augment on the right with an identity matrix. When the reduction is done, denominators in the augmented part provide conditions for which the result will not hold.

Comment: I will try that, but just off the top of my head, would the conditions given by those denominators be different from those given by the numerators in the original? I do realize the advantage is I can use the built-in RREF function. Also, would I augment a 3x3 identity matrix to my 3x2 matrix? My 3x2 has no inverse, so what would be the justification for doing so? Or would you augment with the 3x2 full rank RREF, ie a 2x2 identity with an extra row of 0’s?

Comment: Augment with a full 3x3. At the end row 3 will have zeros in the first two columns, just the same as if you had not augmented. (Late response; just seeing this now.)