# Partitioned Matrix in Display Form in a Notebook

Tags: notebooks, output-formatting

Consider:

$$A=\left[\begin{array}{rrr|rr}
2 & -3 & 1 & 0 & -4\\
1 & 5 & -2 & 3 & -1\\
\hline
0 & -4 & -2 & 7 & -1
\end{array}\right]$$

Let's say I am using a *Mathematica* Notebook and I've used the Writing Assistant to select Math Cells->Equal Symbol Aligned Math Cell. How can I display the partitioned matrix $A$? Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Does this help? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55599/how-to-input-and-output-partitioned-matrices-that-show-partitions-and-compute-as

Answer (score 5):

Borrowing some of the display-related code for `TransformationFunction[]`, I came up with this:

```
MakeBoxes[PartitionedMatrixForm[M_, {p_Integer, q_Integer}], fmt_] ^:= Module[{mat},
          mat = If[Unevaluated[M] =!= {{}} && MatrixQ[Unevaluated[M]] && 
                   And @@ MapThread[0 <= Abs[#2] <= #1 - 1 &, {Dimensions[M], {p, q}}],
                   MakeBoxes[Grid[M, Dividers ->
                               {{False, If[q != 0, {q + Sign[q] -> True}, False]},
                                {False, If[p != 0, {p + Sign[p] -> True}, False]}}], fmt], 
                   MakeBoxes[M, fmt]];
          mat = If[MatchQ[mat, TagBox[_GridBox, "Grid", ___]], 
                   RowBox[{"(", TagBox[mat[[1]], #1 &], ")"}], MakeBoxes[M, fmt]]; 
          mat]
```

which gives
[image: partitioned matrix display]
[image: partitioned matrix display]